# How do I automatically clean the go cache in Visual Code before running tests?

Tags: go

There is a small nuisance with Visual Code and Go, but is mainly related to the most recent release of go 1.11.x and the newly introduced module system. The go builder creates a folder called 'auto' for cached builds, which can be cleaned / deleted via 'go clean -cache'.

Visual Code seems to be confused when executing tests, if such a directory is present, and complains about missing dependencies:

```
/home/user/.golang/src/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert/assertions.go:20:2: could not import github.com/pmezard/go-difflib/difflib (open auto/4c/4cb1f0f2c9f328e3cade99998704759897fd4e530af38db25c85cdc253c1f1a0-d: no such file or directory)
```

is there any possibility to fix this? Or is it just another setting I forgot to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the environment variable `GOCACHE=off`.

Comment: How Embarrassing. That's it. Thank you.

Comment: The disadvantage is, that go modules can't be used outside of GOPATH, when GOCACHE=off is set.

Answer (score 1):

Warning from [issue 26809 ("GOCACHE=off causes modules to exit the tests")](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26809#issuecomment-410477084):

> The `GOCACHE` env variable will be phased out out in 1.12, and cannot be used with `go modules` enabled in 1.11

Configuring VSCode to use using `go test -count=1 ...` is safer.

The [Go 1.12 release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#gocache) (for February 2019) makes that official:

> ### Build cache requirement
>
> The build cache is now required as a step toward eliminating `$GOPATH/pkg`.
> Setting the environment variable `GOCACHE=off` will cause `go` commands that write to the cache to fail.

Answer (score 1):

**In 2022...**

1. Open VSCode's settings.json. To open settings.json, press `Ctrl` + `,` (or `Cmd`+`,` on Mac), then click the Open JSON button shown below. Optionally, if you don't want to set this globally, you can create a `.vscode/settings.json` file at the project root.

   [image: Button for settings.json file]
2. Set the `go.testFlags` value in settings.json:

   ```
    {    
        "go.testFlags": ["-count=1"]
    }
   ```
3. Save and enjoy.

Note: these steps ensure test cache will be skipped *every time* like OP desires. If you instead want a one-time fix, then run `go clean -testcache` in the terminal.